# get height of a division in php, using simple_html_dom

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

```
  <div id="divReportHeader">
     <div class="row-fluid">                                            
        <div class="SpanSimple" style="width: 569px; height: 26.456692913px;
                  margin:0px; border: 2px solid black;">    
            <div style="font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-size: 26.66px;
             text-align: center; vertical-align: text-top;
                font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;"> 
               Country Details
            </div>                                          
       </div>                                       
   </div>
</div>
```

i have the above html inside the php variable `$headerHtml`, I want to get height of the division `.SpanSimple` including `boarder-width`,`margin-top` and `margin-bottom`. i have tried the below code using `simple_html_dom` for getting height, but it doesn't help.

```
$html = str_get_html($headerHtml); 
$e = $html->find("div", 2);
echo $e->height;
```

any suggestions or references?

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server side language and I doubt you can use it to obtain the height of a division.

However, you can use javascript to do that:

```
$(".SpanSimple").height()
```

Comment: i dont want to use jquery, only with php.. this is not an expected answer!

Comment: @chriz you cannot get height of a div using php only

Comment: @TheGuest for every problem there is a solution, see the other answer its leading to light.

Comment: @chriz Yes, I agree. But if you wanna fly you need to use a plane not a ship

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, and in your case it is :

`echo $e->style;`

And you will get parameters like :

`width: 569px; height: 26.456692913px; margin:0px; border: 2px solid black;`

For further details `print_r($e)` or `var_dump($e)` will help you.

Comment: its leading to some solution, i 'll try. my vote limit reached today. i'll upvote ur answer tomorrow. and tanx for ur time!

Comment: i figured it out check my anser

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, what i did is i got the attribute `style` of the div using `simple_html_dom`. and then i splitted that string to an array, then the element after the `height` element will be the height.

```
$html = str_get_html($headerHtml); 
$e = $html->find("div", 2);
$tempStyleArray = array_map('trim', preg_split( "/[:;]+/", $e->style ));
$tempKey = array_search('height', $tempStyleArray);
$tempHeight = substr($tempStyleArray[$tempKey+1], 0, -2); //removing 'px'
echo $tempHeight;
```